# Efficient way of getting listing of files in large filesystem

Tags: unix, filesystems, ls

What is the most efficient way to get a "ls"-like output of the most recently created files in a very large unix file system (100 thousand files +)?

Have tried ls -a and some other varients.

Comment: Are you familiar with the `find` command?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `less` to search and scroll it easily.

`ls -la | less`

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly try

```
ls -a | tail
```

More information [here](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/utail.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If the files are in a single directory, then you can use:

`ls -lt | less`

the -t option to ls will sort the files by modification time and `less` will let you scroll through them

If the want recent files across an entire file system --- i.e., in different directories, then you can use the `find` command:

`find dir -mtime 1 -print | xargs ls -ld`

Substitute the directory where you want to start the search for "dir".  The `find` command will print the names of all of the files that have been modified in the last day (`-mtime 1` means modified in the last one day) and the `xargs` command will take that list of files and feed it to ls, giving you the ls-like output you want